# Articles on matchstick puzzles

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, recreational-mathematics

There are many ingenious puzzles involving matchsticks that are arranged as squares, rectangles or triangles, and can be moved under some restrictions (for a lot of examples see http://www.learning-tree.org.uk/phpBB3/viewforum.php?f=1). I wonder if there are any mathematical article about this kind of problems.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion :-)

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search came up with [this paper](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/tm/30/tm1613.pdf), although I'm not sure it covers what you are asking for.

And if you're into this kind of puzzles, [this book](http://books.google.nl/books?id=EAVDP41jo58C&dq=matchstick+puzzles&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=db_yUpvJN5SShgf7g4HICw&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAA) may be something for you :)

Comment: Thank you. However the article and the book that you linked, are not yet what I am looking for. I am interested in articles studying matchsticks problems in general like: "given n matchsticks...", instead of particular (finite) puzzles.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you may not be able to find such articles as the figures can vary a lot. 
However, I can present a problem...
Use 9 matchsticks to create a square and 2 diamonds.
I can tell you the answer if you need it.